Gnome Extensions of Ubuntu 24.04 (especially System Monitor)
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 I was surprised that almost none of my gnome extensions work. I looked through all of the dozen or so System Monitor extensions on the Gnome website, all but one show error and that one gives very minimal info.
I presume the issue is Gnome-Shell 46. At any rate does anyone know of a working system monitor extension that I missed, or some workaround?

Most of the extensions in my system are now available in Gnome 46 and working fine. Check the Gnome version it is available on your Gnome extension webpage. Can you mention the name of the extension that you are using?

Does this extension work for you: system-monitor-next??

This does not answer the question, but my extensions, arcmenu, forcequit,openweather, vitals, would turn off after sleep mode. I would have to turn them on each time. Also the dock would disappear. Back to 22.04

Not a real solution, but I managed to work around this issue (based on the installation guide on the new gnome extension site) firstly by uninstalling chrome-gnome-shell:
sudo apt-get remove chrome-gnome-shell

and then installing gnome-browser-connector:
sudo apt-get install gnome-browser-connector

Secondly, I updated the gnome shell integration add-on of Firefox browser and gave it full permission. Then extensions from new gnome extension site were installable as usual by clicking the install button on the website.
Though my installation was a fresh install, not an upgrade like yours.
